# Ostrow, Ostrowez, or Ostroweic Russia before 1907- where now?

Tags: 19th-century, 20th-century, poland, russia, historical-gazetteer

My relatives were from Ostrow, Ostrowez, or Ostroweic Russia before 1907. Is this now in Poland? Where?

I will be travelling to Poland in a month and I would like to find this place.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the 2-minute [Tour] of the site to learn about its protocols.  This may or may not be relevant but this Wikipedia page might be of interest to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Ostr%C3%B3w

Comment: @PolyGeo The Ostrów you're linking to was part of Germany in 1907 if I'm not mistaken, so it is ruled out.

Comment: 'Ostrów' meant 'non-flooding island' in old Slavic language, I'm afraid there are hundreds places by that name, as it was a preferable location for settlements (some of them are now districts of other cities).

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Your question is missing a critical element, which is how you know where your relatives came from.  If you could post snippets of any record images showing the place name, and tell us which documents they came from, while leaving out the names of the people on the document, that would give us a better way to analyze the information you have, while still preserving your family's privacy.

Answer (score 6):

"Ostroweic" doesn't seem like a plausible name in Polish language, very likely it is "Ostrówiec" or "Ostrowice". There is [dozens](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/2105378928) [of](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/31584856) [villages](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3950042) [all](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/3009733379) [over](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/3009676078) [Poland](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/3009733378) with that name, including [one relatively large town in Belarus which was Polish before the second world war](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/40799236#map=12/54.5948/25.9298).

There is also a surprisingly large pound of small villages called *Ostrów*, in both Poland and Belarus, there's too many of them so I cannot list them all.

*Ostrowez* is most certainly not possibly a Polish name.

[Ostrowice](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/31584860#map=13/53.6042/15.9762) cannot be the village you're looking for, because it was German before the first world war.

Let's not [forget](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/337540439) [several](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/337552128) [villages](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/337522582) [called](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/337522383) *Ostriv* in western Ukraine, very likely at least some of those were Polish before the second world war - they would translate to Ostrów in Polish (similarly to Kiev<->Kijów, Lviv<->Lwów or Krakiv<->Kraków)

Finally I'll mention it, this place has definitely never been Polish, but there is a relatively large Russian town called [Ostrow](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/4498726#map=10/57.2982/28.6623) close to the border with Lativa.

**Without further information it's impossible to tell which of those locations is "your" Ostrówiec / Ostrów**

Answer (score 1):

I am 100% sure this is city name not human one.

Correct city name can be Ostrowiec or Ostrów but unfortunately there is multiple small cities named like both above.
You can also try search Ostrowiec Świętokrzyski or Ostrów Wielkopolski

Answer (score 0):

Egor(Igor) Kozlovsky brother of my grand-grand father Nikita Kozlovsky imigrated to USA around 1914 from Osowiec (now it's Belarua). They lost the connection because of the political situation.